# How to use functionals with a list or vector of functions?

Tags: r, list, function

I want to use functionals to calculate different summary statistics onto an data set / simulation.

```
choose_summary <- function(f) f(1:100)
choose_summary(mean)
choose_summary(median)
choose_summary(max)
```

Thats an easy example on how this should work. I want to use a list of functions to be applied to the data, but it doesnt work the way I expected it to.

```
sum_fun_list <- list(mean, max, median)
choose_summary(sum_fun_list [1])
```

Output:    Error in f(1:100) : could not find function "f"

What I tried to to is get a element of the list and use it as input for my function, but that doesnt seem to work. It looks like R doesnt recognize the input as a function. I have no idea how to work around that. I tried different approaches like `unlist()` or `as.function()` but nothing seems to do the trick. Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`do.call` is your friend here.

We can make a list of functions and a vector:

```
funs <- list(mean,median,max)
my_vec <- list(1:100)
```

Then use `sapply` to call any function in `funs` with the argument `my_vec`

```
sapply(funs,do.call,my_vec)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you're indexing the list of functions. This works:

```
choose_summary(sum_fun_list[[1]])
[1] 50.5
```

and so does this:

```
sapply(sum_fun_list, choose_summary)
[1]  50.5 100.0  50.5
```

When you index a list using `[...]`, as in `sum_fun_list[1]` you return a *list* with one element. When you index a list with `[[...]]` you get the contents of that element (which is the function in your case).